# Multiplication Assignment Operator when variable is 0

Tags: javascript, python

why the result of the following operation is always 0 in the Python REPL? (got the same results for C and Javascript)

```
>>> a = 0
>>> a *= 1 + 1
>>> a
0
```

Shouldn't the multiplication assignment be equivalent to a = a * 1 + 1 in the case above?

```
>>> a = 0
>>> a = a * 1 + 1
>>> a
1
```

Comment: No. The right hand expression is evaluated before the assignment, see the section *AssignmentExpression* within [*ECMA-262 §12.15.4*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Answer (score 3):

because

```
a *= 1 + 1
```

is the same as

```
a = a *(1 + 1)
```

since a is 0 then the result is still 0

Answer (score 0):

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), expression is evaluated first

> 4. Let rref be the result of **evaluating AssignmentExpression.**
> 5. Let r be the result of **applying op to lval and rval as if evaluating the expression lval op rval**.

So, expression on the right hand side is evaluated first before applying the operation and assignment.

```js
var a = 2;
a *= 0 + 2;
console.log( "multiplication " + a ); //4 since 2*(0+2) is 4

a = 1;
a /= 0 + 2;
console.log( "division " + a ); //0.5 since 1/(0+2) is 0.5
```